# forceDelete method not working as expected in laravel 5 project (can't delete model from the database)

Tags: php, laravel-5, soft-delete

I working (editing) on project base on laravel 5.8
in the database I have "contacts" table
main columns are :

( `id` ,`name`, .. ,`deleted_at` , `deleted_by` `agency_id`  `contactable_id` ... )

so when is use **$model->delete()**  for **soft delete** it will **work very well**

> before delete
> ( `id :1` ,`name: 'name'`, .. ,`deleted_at : null` , `deleted_by :null` `agency_id : 1`  `contactable_id : 1`)

> after delete
> ( `id :1` ,`name: 'name'`, .. ,`deleted_at : (dateValue)` , `deleted_by :1` `agency_id : 1`  `contactable_id : 1`)

```php
class ContactController extends Controller
{
 public function delete(Request $request)
    {


        if ($request->ajax()) {
            \Log::info($request->contact_id);
            try {
                $deleted = $this->model_instance::find($request->contact_id)->delete();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                \Log::info($ex->getMessage());
            }
            if ($deleted) {
                $log_message = trans('contacts.delete_log') . '#' . $request->contact_id;
                //logActivity($log_message);
                return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'deleted_successfully']);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'fail_while_delete']);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route($this->index_route);
    }
}
```

so when is use **$model->forceDelete()**  for **delete for ever from the database (forceDelete)** it will **not work as expected** but will fill `deleted_by` with user number and keep deleted_at with `null` value

> before force delete
> ( `id :1` ,`name: 'name'`, .. ,`deleted_at : null` , `deleted_by :null` `agency_id : 1`  `contactable_id : 1`)

> after  force delete
> ( `id :1` ,`name: 'name'`, .. ,`deleted_at : null` , `deleted_by :1` `agency_id : 1`  `contactable_id : 1`)

```php
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function forceDelete(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            \Log::info($request->contact_id);
            try {
                $deleted = $this->model_instance::withTrashed()->find($request->contact_id)->forceDelete();
              
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                \Log::info($ex->getMessage());
            }
            // if ($deleted) {
            //     $log_message = trans('contacts.delete_log') . '#' . $request->contact_id;
            //     return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'deleted_successfully']);
            // } else {
            //     return response()->json(['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'fail_while_delete']);
            // }
        }
        // return redirect()->route($this->index_route);
    }
}
```

`forceDelete()` return true

---

so this method work like this or there problem in my code in some where(I mean not jsut the previos code ) ?!

use softdelete
in some cases use delete (for soft delete)
and other cases use forceDelete (for delete from the database)

---

for soft delete it worked very well
for force delete it takes another scenario

Comment: Is this correct? `deleted_at : 1` This should show a timestamp, not an integer

Comment: @aynber oh sorry .. no no this value but timestamp value .. updated

Answer (score 0):

```php
$deleted = $this->model_instance::find($request->contact_id)->forceDelete();
```

Will not work.

Use `where` instead of `find`:

```php
$deleted = $this->model_instance::where('id', $request->contact_id)->forceDelete();
```

This will work very well.